# How to translate SQL filters for cx_oracle query execution

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I couldn't find any answer (maybe I didn't search enough) how to use filtering not just the straight way where you have `"WHERE column_x=:filter_value"` 
which is achieved by passing a dictionary 
`cursor.execute(query, {'column_x':filter_value})` 
where an exact filter value is provided but a more flexible filtering, like

```
    WHERE FACT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-12-21','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND TO_DATE('2017-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND TYPE_ID NOT IN (2,3)
```

Does some one know how to do it the best way without putting it into the query string? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to avoid in the query string exactly ? why not use a dictionary with multiple keys to match each filter parameter ?

Comment: @PRMoureu That's probably a good workaround, but if you have 999 exclusions it might be not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something along these lines:

`def query_with_filter(cursor, baseSql, **conditions):
    whereClause = " and ".join("%s = :%s" % (n, n) for n in conditions)
    sql = baseSql if not conditions else baseSql + " where %s" % whereClause
    cursor.execute(sql, conditions)`

which can then be used like this:

This has some limitations:

```
1) the conditions have to be valid column names
2) you are limited to simple conditions
```

The second limitation can be overcome by allowing for special suffixes as in

```
fact_date__between__ = (date1, date2)
type_id__notin__ = (2, 3)
```

but you then need to strip those off and adjust the calculation of the where clause accordingly. That should be enough to get you started if you want to proceed this way. I did something similar to this myself at a previous job and it worked fairly well, I thought!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I will use SQLalchemy. It actually has all functions you need. Else I would be writing string-formatting functions with all of the conditions myself...